# reference to parent of object in inheritance

Tags: c++

I have the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using vec = std::vector<double>;

class my_vec
: public vec
{
    public:
        my_vec(int size)
        :vec(size, 0)
        {}

        my_vec(int size, double val)
        :vec(size, val)
        {}
};


int main() 
{
    my_vec v1 (6);
    my_vec v2 (6,3);

    std::vector<double>& v3 = v1;
    v3[0] = 10;
    v3.push_back(10);

    std::cout << "Finish" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In this code I have a class `my_vec` which inherits from `stl`'s `vector<double>`.
I am creating a couple of `my_vec` objects.

Then I am creating a reference to the parent class of an object and performing some operations which are reflected on the original object.

Question: Does the operation `parent&` v3 = `child` have a name?

Is this object slicing?

Comment: Perhaps *downcasting*?

Comment: Define 'parent'. Do you mean 'base class'?

Comment: Just as a side note: Correct type for indicating sizes is not `int`, but `std::size_t` (you'd need to `#include <cstddef>` for if it wasn't coming along with `<vector>` already in given case).

Comment: `std::vector` is not intended to be inherited from! Don't do so, you're doomed to run into trouble sooner or later otherwise.

Comment: FYI: [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: You are simply initialising a *reference* of base type to an object of derived type. Nothing more. Object slicing doesn't occur in this case. It does, if you assign an object of derived type to an *object* of base type, as in `std::vector<double> v3 = v1;` (note: no reference!), though in given case there isn't really anything to be sliced away…

Comment: @AlexeyS.Larionov No, downcasting would be the exact opposite. This is upcasting.

Comment: Whatever you might think inheritance is rarely the solution. And you can see std::vector is not intended to be inherited from because it lacks a virtual destructor (ideally it should have been marked final but that cannot be retroactively applied to the standard now)

Answer (score 1):

No. This is not object slicing.

This is object slicing:

```
std::vector<double> v3 = v1;
```

Here all parts of `vec` not present in `std::vector<double>` would get lost. Though, as `vec` has no additional members, nothing catastrophic would happen. Nevertheless, slicing is to be avoided.

> Does the operation parent& v3 = child have a name?

No. There is no special term for this.

---

PS: Do note that `std::vector`, like most other standard types, is not meant to be inherited from publicly. It can be done, but it is a source of many issues. Most prominently, the following will not work correctly:

```
 std::vector<double>* x = new vec;
 delete x;
```

because `std::vector` has no virtual destructor. However, this two lines are expected to be totally fine when `vec` publicly inherits from `std::vector<double>`.